# Unknown entity when running junit test

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, junit

I've got a Java EE Project in my eclipse and i'm using hibernate. But i don't know why when i run my Junit tests i got an unknown entity error.

The thing is that when i run it from my tomcat server calling the method from my servlet everything go fine.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.calamar.beans.Application
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1149)
at com.calamar.dao.ApplicationDao.addApplication(ApplicationDao.java:32)
at com.calamar.services.ApplicationService.addApplication(ApplicationService.java:48)
at com.calamar.test.TestApplicationService.initializeTest(TestApplicationService.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Here the class : 
    package com.calamar.beans;

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "calamar.application")
public class Application 
{
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "application_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "application_seq_gen", sequenceName = "calamar.application_id_seq",initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private int id;
    [...]
}
```

The code that is called on ApplicationDao.addApplication(ApplicationDao.java:32) ([...].persist(application)) :

```
    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(application); 
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    entityManager.close();
```

And my persistence.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="calamar" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>beans.Application</class>
        <class>beans.Derogation</class>
        <class>beans.DerogationAutre</class>
        <class>beans.DerogationFille</class>
        <class>beans.DerogationLinux</class>
        <class>beans.DerogationOracle</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="..."/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="..."/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="..."/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I hope you will find what is wrong in my code.

Thx

Comment: Your class is named `com.calamar.beans.Application`. But in your persistence.xml, you have `<class>beans.Application</class>`.

Comment: @JB Nizet Thx man it was that ! But why does it work when i run the project on a tomcat server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **class** element in persistence.xml is distinct from the package of Application class:

```
Unknown entity: com.calamar.beans.Application
```

but

```
<class>beans.Application</class>
```

Comment: Thx ! It was that ! Same question, why does it work when i run the project on a tomcat server but not when i run the JUnit test from Eclipse ?

Comment: From official docs (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cfgdepds005.htm) it is said that it can find annotated entities int the root of PU. The root of the persistence unit is the JAR file or directory, whose META-INF directory contains the persistence.xml file. Suppose for Tomcat your class is picked from root of PT but for Unit tests not (because of the different class loading mechanism)